# how do you remove rear wheel on scott genius 920?

Tags: rear-wheel

It does not have quick release. You obviously unwind a lever on one side which unscrews the gear side from frame ... but once this is done there is no obvious way to me how to progress. All Scotts manuals ignore the issue making me think it is really simple (and I'm really stupid!) or has to go to the shop!!! unlikely

Comment: Does it have dropouts or is it a "through-hole" mounting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any images just a description. Apparently it is similar to a conventional skewer. The difference is, the skewer is removed to drop the wheel out of the frame. The nut that typically is not removed is captured in the frame. Some owners have complained it is difficult to line up the skewer with the "nut"

Comment: Cheers. Thank you. I was expecting that to be the case but it was seized in position and I was scared to force it in case there was a subtlety I had missed. I gentle tapped it out (after undoing it) have now cleaned it up and oiled and reassembled. Thanks